# Prevent Duplicating Typescript Path Configurations in Monorepo

Tags: typescript, jestjs, bazel, monorepo, module-alias

## Gist

I like to follow the "dry" (don't repeat yourself) principle. But currently I have nearly the same path configuration in three different places:

#### 1. Typescript config file

I have a monorepo with multiple Bazel Typescript packages, and thus I need to reference them with paths like this inside `tsconfig.json`

```
"paths": {
  "@cents-ideas/enums": ["./packages/enums"],
  "@cents-ideas/utils": ["./packages/utils"],
  "@cents-ideas/event-sourcing": ["./packages/event-sourcing"],
  "@cents-ideas/models": ["./packages/models"]
},
```

#### 2. Node package file

For development with `ts-node` I also need to add the paths to the `package.json` so that Node.Js can recognize the Typescript aliases. (I am using a package called [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) for this.

```
"_moduleAliases": {
  "@cents-ideas/enums": "./packages/enums",
  "@cents-ideas/utils": "./packages/utils",
  "@cents-ideas/event-sourcing": "./packages/event-sourcing",
  "@cents-ideas/models": "./packages/models"
}
```

#### 3. Jest config file

Finally I also need to add those paths to my Jest config, so that the tests can find the paths:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^@cents-ideas/utils(.*)$': '<rootDir>/packages/utils$1',
  '^@cents-ideas/event-sourcing(.*)$': '<rootDir>/packages/event-sourcing$1',
  '^@cents-ideas/enums(.*)$': '<rootDir>/packages/enums$1',
  '^@cents-ideas/models(.*)$': '<rootDir>/packages/models$1',
},
```

## Goal

My goal is to have one common place where I can put the paths and all other places will be updated automatically.

---

Just in case you need further insight into the project, you can check it out here: https://github.com/flolude/cents-ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Typescript config file

```
"paths": {
  "@cents-ideas/*": ["./packages/*"]
},
```

## Node package file

```
const moduleAlias = require('module-alias');

const registerAliases = () => {
  if (process.env.ENV === 'dev') {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const paths: string[] = fs.readdirSync('./packages');
    paths.forEach(addPackageAlias);
  }
};

const addPackageAlias = (name: string) => {
  moduleAlias.addAlias(`@cents-ideas/${name}`, `${__dirname}../../../packages/${name}`);
};

registerAliases();
```

## Jest config file

Fixed with the help of Bazel. But I am sure that Jest supports similar wildcards as the Typescript config.

Answer (score 0):

You're using yarn, so probably you should take a look into [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/). You should be able to add

**`package.json`**

```
{
  //...
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*
  ]
}
```

And run `yarn` which will make symlinks into `node_modules` and you should be able to remove all of the three configurations above

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention this. But I've actually moved away from yarn workspaces because of incompatibility reasons with Bazel